# php - add new index to array without generating an 'undefined index' warning

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I am looping over an array,

if I spot an error in the array I am adding a key called error.

however I am getting a whole pile of 'undefined index 'error' warnings.

How can I do this without generating those warnings?

---

**Code as requested**

```
$csv = array();
if (($handle = fopen($filePath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($csv[] = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE);
  fclose($handle);
}

foreach ($csv as &$row) {
  if (count($row) > $maxCols)
    $maxCols = count($row);

  if (count($row) == 0) {
    $errors++;
    $row['error'] = 'Empty Column!';
    continue;
  }
  //more code
}
```

---

**Example of what $row would look like in the `foreach()`**

> Array (
>    [0] => 1
>    [1] => 12
>    [2] => 64273566141
>    [3] => bakery
>    [4] => 2009-12-08 09:07:39
>    [5] => 2009
>    [6] => 2009-12-08 09:08:35
>    [7] =>
>    [8] => 0 
>   )

---

**See?** [Full Size](http://webspirited.com/proof.png)
http://webspirited.com/proof.png

Comment: can you please show some code?

Comment: and no, I cant add an empty index when I create the array as it comes from `fgetcsv`

Comment: `isset` or `array_key_exists` are the usual solutions to this error, but code please, cause given what you are describing you shouldn't be getting this error unless i've misunderstood what you are asking

Comment: that code shouldn't produce an error... I think the error is more likely to be where you are checking for the error later (i.e. expand the `//more code` comment please)

Comment: Where is the `E_NOTICE` error occurring? In the `//more code` section? Nothing you have there would throw an undefined index error.

Comment: @tobyodavies: according to php it is on the line that has `$row['error'] = 'Empty Column!';` because the 'error' index does not exists untill I try to set a value to it. But, because I am creating the array from fgetcsv it means I cant add the index on creation without making the array myself which is a bunch of extra code :/

Comment: @Hailwood That doesn't make sense. The syntax `$array['new-index'] = 'val'` is the same as using `array_push()`, ie it's perfectly valid. I think you're looking at the wrong line

Comment: checkout the image... So yes, different line, but the purpose of the line is the same.

Comment: @Hailwood Look closer at the difference between your question and the screenshot. See my updated answer

Comment: Repeat this mantra - "I will always post actual code snippets on SO"

Comment: "I will always post actual code snippets on SO" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `==` instead of `=`.

Using the comparison operator is attempting to fetch the potentially undefined array index. If `$row['error']` has not been set previously, this will trigger an `E_NOTICE` undefined index error.

Comment: nope, Im adding the error index to all 'rows' of the csv array that have errors. Please see my code above

Comment: @Hailwood Edited my answer given the new information in your question